# How to use Assert in Junit instead of if else?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have a method for searching that on the first page there is a link to wikipedia:

```
public void findWiki() {

    TryLink = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA']"));

    if (TryLink.isDisplayed()) {
        System.out.println("Yes link is there");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No link is there");
    }
}
```

Implementation of this method:

```
@Test
public void googleSearchPF() {
    chromeDriver.get("https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi88p6D9vbyAhXhkIsKHffmA_oQPAgI");
    GoogleSearchPF googleSearchPF = PageFactory.initElements(chromeDriver, GoogleSearchPF.class);
    googleSearchPF.find("Gladiolus");
    googleSearchPF.findWiki();
}
```

The test works, everything is OK - it finds the link. But how can I implement a link check using assertTrue? If so, how exactly?

It seems that it should be implemented somehow like this:

```
Assertions.assertTrue(googleSearchPF.getAllElements().stream().anyMatch(x->x.isDisplayed()),
        "Wikipedia was not found");
```

Comment: Is this really a test and no business code? Why don't you just do `assertTrue(TryLink.isDisplayed())`?

Comment: Why is `googleSearchPF` annotated with `@Test`? As far as I can see, that method itself is not a test.

Comment: This is not a business code. googleSearchPF - a really working test. I just want to figure out how to write correctly Assert method so that I can correctly check the link without using if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see `assertTrue` :

```
assertTrue
public static void assertTrue(java.lang.String message,
                              boolean condition)
Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't it throws an AssertionError with the given message.
Parameters:
message - the identifying message for the AssertionError (null okay)
condition - condition to be checked
```

Now, Your `findWiki()` method does contains if and else block, which I believe you want to assert and get rid off of that traditional `if else` to check the `conditions`.

**Code :**

```
public void findWiki() {
    List<WebElement> TryLink = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA']"));
    int size = TryLink.size() ;
    assertTrue(size > 0, "try link exists"); 
}
```

Basically we are using `findElements` and checking the size if it's `>0` then parse inside `assertTrue.` Like this `assertTrue(size > 0, "try link exists");`

Comment: The code works, but why does it not write in the console after executing the program "try link exists". Or should nothing be written? I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to figure out in detail how it works

Comment: The text used in assertion will be displayed in case of failure only.

Comment: @OttoRahn :  This is correct (Or should nothing be written?) ,  also do you have junit report ? if so, it would be seen in reports

Comment: @Prophet :  I hope you understand what assertions are meant for.

Comment: @cruisepandey I hope I do  :)

Comment: @OttoRahn : See, console writing can be done via so many ways, we are not concerns about console writing when we use Assertions, Assertions are basically to tell if the step has been executed successfully or not. to write in console please use loggers not assertions. If the step is failed, then you would see all the relevant details in reports, if passed, then text should be ideally visible in reports. Typically a report should be kept here `eclipse-workspace\ProjectName\test-output`

Comment: @Prophet :  I have added a comment above, I hope this will clarify the things and confusion.

Comment: @cruisepandey 100% agree with you

Comment: Also, pay attention to `findElements` which I have used in my code, elements will never throw any exceptions. Either it will have some web elements, or empty list. This is basically the reason why we will never encounter no such element exception.

Answer (score 1):

To make your `findWiki()` with assertion can be done as following:

```java
public void findWiki() {

    TryLink = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA']"));

    assertTrue(TryLink.isDisplayed(),"No link is there"));
}
```

Comment: What is `actualString` here?

Comment: if the element is not found it is gonna throw `NoSuchElement` exception followed by `assertion failure`

Comment: @cruisepandey correct. I just translated the existing method to use assertion instead of `if-else` as asked by OP in the title.

Comment: In case of an error in the link, it does not display an error message

Comment: What do you mean by `In case of an error in the link`? I see you are validation the element is displayed.

Comment: I don't get an exception in the console if there is no link, as specified in the second parameter "No link is there".

Comment: That's because your logic is wrong! In case there is no link you will never reach this assertion because it applies the assertion on `TryLink.isDisplayed()` while if element is not found driver will throw exception before that

Comment: I understood. The program will simply stop at this check. Then there is no point in writing the second parameter: ...,"No link is there"));

Comment: Or you should assert for some other condition. maybe for the link presence. Or not to use assertions, just to use log as mentioned by cruisepandey

Comment: Now you can upvote our answers and accept one of them...